# What is the pH of kvass?

Tags: acid-base, ph, food-chemistry

I know that it is less than 7.0, but would be nice to know exact value of pH of natural fermented kvass (not soda-like counterfeit). Another aspect is to know if kvass is more gentle than Cola (pH=2.5) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this paper](http://llufb.llu.lv/conference/foodbalt/2014/FoodBalt_Proceedings_2014-188-191.pdf)$^{[1]}$, the kvas in their study started out at a pH of 6.1 prior to fermentation, then became stable at about a pH of 3.8 after 12 hours.  This is of course significantly less acidic than a cola with a pH of 2.5 (and some colas can have a pH closer to 2).

1) *QUALITY CHANGES OF NATURALLY FERMENTED KVASS DURING PRODUCTION STAGES, Department of Food Technology, Faculty of Food Technology, Latvia University of Agriculture, Liela Street2, Jelgava, Latvia*

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot !!! I couldn't get answer on Quora for two days, and here I got it so fast.

Comment: No problem, I'm very glad it was helpful :)